# guardar una IP en una base de datos

Tags: php

Buenos días
Estoy intentando crear una base de datos para guardar los "likes" que el usuario da. Para ello necesito guardar la IP para que una misma persona no voto de forma repetida.

El problema es que obtengo la IP pero no me la guarda (o al menos no la muestra)
Necesito ayuda, por favor.
Os paso el código:

alta.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<?php
    function getRealIP()
    {

    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))
    {
        return $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
    }
    elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
    {
        return $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    }
    elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"]))
    {
        return $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"];
    }
    elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
    {
        return $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    }
    elseif (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"]))
    {
        return $_SERVER["HTTP_FORWARDED"];
    }
    else
    {
        return $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }

    }

     $ip= getRealIP();
    //echo $ip."<br/>"; 
    $_POST['ip']=$ip;
    echo $_POST['ip']."ESTE";//hasta aqui, bien
?>


  <form method="post" action="altab.php">
    Correo:<br/>
    <input type="text" name="correo" />
    <input type="hidden" id="dir" name="ip" >
    <input type="hidden"  name="fecha" >

    <input type="submit" value="listo">
  </form>


<script type="text/javascript">//aqui no entra o no hace nada
   var ip=<?php echo $ip; ?>;
   alert ("hola");
   alert(ip);
    document.getElementById("dir").value=ip;
</script>




</body>
</html>


altab.php
<?php 
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
include('includes/conexion.php');//Incluimos la conexión
  $acentos = $enlace->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

  $query="INSERT INTO datos(correo,ip)  VALUES 
('{$_POST['correo']}','{$_POST['ip']}')";

if (mysqli_query($enlace,$query)){
                   echo $_POST['ip'];
                   echo 'hecho<br/><a href="index.php">Volver al Indice</a> <br/>';
                }
                else{
                    echo "<p>Hubo algún problema. Inténtelo más tarde</p>"; }

    ?>



listar.php
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
include('includes/conexion.php');//Incluimos la conexión
        $acentos = $enlace->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $query = "SELECT * FROM datos";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($enlace,$query)){
            while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {           
            echo "correo: ".$fila['correo']."<br/>";
            echo "IP: ".$fila['ip']."<br/>";
            echo "fecha: ".$fila['fecha']."<br/>";

            echo "<hr/>";
            }
        }
        ?>
<a href="index.php">Volver al Indice</a> <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

la base de datos se llama "clientes" y la tabla es "datos"

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `datos` (
  `correo` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `fecha` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`correo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;
```

Volcado de datos para la tabla `datos`

```
INSERT INTO `datos` (`correo`, `ip`, `fecha`) VALUES
('p@p.pp', '', ''),
('r@j.y', '', ''),
('r@y.f', '', ''),
('s@h.f', '', '');
```

Comment: Ojo, el script se ejecuta segun se lee por lo que si aun no esta formado el DOM no va a funcionar.

Comment: Otro ojo: tu código es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. En lugar de crear sentencias dinámicas, deberías usar sentencias preparadas

Comment: Gracias Alvaro pero creo que todavía no llego a ese tipo de cosas. Soy muy novata. De hecho no sé cuál es la diferencia.

Comment: para comenzar yo cambiaria un par de cosas, meteria un  <body onload="getRealIP()"> => esto que asigne al document.getElementById("dir").value=ip;, para asegurarnos que esta cargado deberia aprecerte el valor, cambia el hidden a text provisionalmente para ver si te esta cargando la ip

Comment: Lo siento, no lo muestra. Gracias de todos modos

Comment: Prueba a poner 
`var ip='<?php echo $ip; ?>';` (comillas, importante, ten en cuenta que el tipo de variable no se pasa desde PHP a JS, así que tienes que indicarle que es un string poniendo comillas)

Comment: @Gema la diferencia entre usar sentencias dinámicas (concatenando cadenas como lo haces) o usar sentencias preparadas (o parametrizadas) es que las segundas son más seguras. Con el código que tienes, si un usuario malicioso dice que su ip es `0'); DROP TABLE datos;--` te borra la tabla datos y te deja en una posición delicada. Nunca es demasiado pronto para hacer segura una aplicación, y no hay ninguna buena excusa para que una aplicación sea insegura.

Comment: Gracias. Ya voy entendiendo un poco más. Con tiempo y paciencia.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te muestro un código que he probado en phpfiddle y funciona.

He aplicado algunas de las indicaciones que te han hecho los compañeros en comentarios, sobre todo lo de las consultas preparadas, para poder introducir tus datos de forma segura.

***Nota:*** La segunda parte del código es solamente una prueba, para mostrar que funciona.

**código**

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9dmt-bwhr)**</kbd>

```
<?php

require "util/public_db_info.php";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $pass_word, $database_name, $port);

    /*
        * Las consultas preparadas sustituyen los valores reales
        * por signos de interrogación en MySQLi
    */
    $sql = "INSERT INTO datos (correo, ip) VALUES (?, ?)";    

    /*
        * Almacenar en variables los datos a insertar
        * Cambia las variables puestas a mano 
        * por las variables obtenidas por $_POST
    */
    $correo= "my-correo@yo.com";  //$_POST['email'];
    $ip= get_client_ip();         //$_POST['ip'];;

    //Preparar la consulta
    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

    //Evaluar si  la preparación tuvo  éxito
    if ($stmt) 
    {
         /*
           * Pasar parámetros separados  de la instrucción SQL
           * la letras "ss" indican el tipo de cada dato que se va a insertar
           * s: String, si es una cadena , i: Integer, si fuera un entero, etc
           * Ejecutar
        */
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $correo,$ip);
        $stmt->execute();

        /*
          * Imprimir la cantidad de filas insertadas usando affected_rows
        */

        printf("%d Filas insertadas.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

        /*
         * Cerrar $stmt y luego la conexión
         * para liberar recursos
        */

    $stmt->close();
}

    // Comprobar si se insertaron los datos
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM datos";   

    if ($resultado = $mysqli->query($sql)) 
    {
           echo "<pre>";

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))  
        {
           echo $row["correo"]." : ".$row["ip"];
        }

            echo "</pre>";

        $resultado->close();

    } 
       else 
    {
        echo "No hay datos";
    }

$mysqli->close();



    //Obtiene la IP del cliente

    function get_client_ip() {
        $ipaddress = '';
        if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
        else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
           $ipaddress = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
        else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
            $ipaddress = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        else
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
        return $ipaddress;
    }
    ?>
```

**resultado**

```
-1 Filas insertadas.

my-correo@yo.com : 148.3.73.185
```

Comment: Muchiiiiiiiiisimas gracias. He tenido que hacer algún pequeño cambio pero ya funciona y creo que lo podré adaptar a mi trabajo. Ahora ya seguiré con más alegria

Comment: @Gema me alegro de que ahora te funcione. Para que la pregunta no aparezca como sin resolver considera marcar como solución la respuesta que más haya contribuido a resolver el problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de dos formas distinas.

1- Asignando la variable vía JAVASCRIPT, cómo ya lo estabas intentando, pero declarando correctamente las variables.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//aqui no entra o no hace nada
   var ip = "<?php echo $ip; ?>";
   alert ("hola");
   alert(ip);
   document.getElementById("dir").value=ip;
</script>
```

2- Asignando el valor directamente en el campo a tal fin.

```
<form method="post" action="altab.php">
    Correo:<br/>
    <input type="text" name="correo" />
    <input type="hidden" id="dir" name="ip" value="<?php echo $ip; ?>"> <!-- Podría ser <?=$ip?>, como fomra abreviada -->
    <input type="hidden"  name="fecha" > <!-- Aquí también puedes asignar el valor directamente al campo -->

    <input type="submit" value="listo">
</form>
```

Ambas formas son válidas, aunque encuentra la segunda más adecuada (opinión personal) ya que la asignación es directa y, a menos que necesites procesar dicha información con javascript, es mucho más sencillo.